# Update non state variable in React useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an application the receives new data over a WebSocket every second. Each second I receive 10 to 15 messages that I need to store in and display. I am currently updating a state array each time I receive new data but the effect is that I re-render the screen 10 to 15 times per second.

**What I want to achieve is to store the incoming data in an array but only update the screen once every second.**

My approach that I can't get working is to create a non-state array that is updated when new data is received and copy that data to a state array every second with a timer.

This is the declaration of the state array:

```
  const [boatData2, _setBoatData2] = useState({});
  

  const boatDataRef = useRef(boatData2);
  
  const setBoatData2 = (update) => {
    boatDataRef.current = update;
    _setBoatData2(update);
  }
```

This is the hook code where the data is received:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ws.current) return;
    ws.current.onmessage = e => {
      setDataFlowing(true);
      setDataAge(0);
      setScreenUpdates(screenUpdates => screenUpdates + 1);
      //console.log('New Data');
      const message = JSON.parse(e.data);
      if (message.updates && message.updates.values) {
        message.updates[0].values.forEach(obj => {
          let newPath = obj.path.split('.').join("");
          const update = {
            path: obj.path,
            value: obj.value,
            timestamp: message.updates[0].timestamp,
            valid: true,
            age: 0,
          };
          now = Date.parse(message.updates[0].timestamp);
          setBoatData2({ ...boatDataRef.current, [newPath]: update });
        });
      }
    };
  }, []);
```

This is the code that runs every second:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = null;
    if (isActive) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1);
        let boatdata = boatData2;
        //console.log(boatData3);
        Object.values(boatdata).forEach(val => {
          val.age = val.age + 1;
          if (val.age > 30) {
            val.valid = false;
          }
        });
        setBoatData2(boatdata);
        setDataAge(dataAge => dataAge + 1);

        if (dataAge > 60) {
          setDataFlowing(false);
        }
      }, 1000);
    } else if (!isActive && seconds !== 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [isActive, seconds, boatData2]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the help of `useRef` .

```
const messageRef = useRef([]);
```

This creates a object inside `messageRef` called `current` which we can mutate and mutating it will not trigger a re-render. Now your `messageRef` will be something like this

```
{ 
  current: []
}
```

Now whenever you get the message from the websocket push the message into this ref as

```
messageRef.current.push(your message)
```

Now inside your function which updates the state after some xyz second . You can use this Ref to update the state

```
setYourMessages(messageRef.current);
messageRef.current = []; // do this after you state update call. Else you will be pushing duplicate messages into the state
```